# Marketing Cloud Engagement Split Clicks

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

Unfortunately I haven't been able to resolve the issue using alias tags.

Here is my syntax, and I still can't see this alias in my journey in my Engagement Split:

```
<a href="%%=redirectTo(Concat('https://Sampledomain.com.au/'))=%%" alias="Not Ready" target="_blank">
```

In regards to Impression Tracking, is it just a matter of adding the being and end tags around the ?

Any thoughts on this please?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the a tag that SFMC have in there button default block html?

```
<a href="%%=redirectTo(Concat('https://Sampledomain.com.au/'))=%%" alias="Not Ready" conversion="false" data-linkto="https://"  target="_blank" title="">
```